# not-yet-commons SSL and Open SSL, Java and C++, Common Ground?

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl

The not-yet-commons SLL package for Java provides an OpenSSL object with a method for password based encryption:

encrypt("des", password, data);

This method is said to be compatible with the OpenSSL C library.  My question is, what is the OpenSSL C++ method equivalent to the above Java?

Thanks

Comment: Relating my open-ssl/java experience: if it's not compatible out-of-the-box, look at the openssl options very carefully, sometimes there's an option that's not very well documented but that will make the OpenSSL output completely equivalent to the java one.

Example: when generating elliptic curves keys, add "EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(ec_key, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);" to use the name of the curve (understood by java) instead of the parameters of the curve (understood only by openssl) in the generated public key

Comment: Maybe I can be more specific.  In Java I with not-yet-commons SSL:

    encryptedString = OpenSSL.encrypt("des-ede3-cbc", passwordBytes, dataBytes);

In OpenSSL in C, I can do something like this:

     EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), 
         (const unsigned char *)mykey, iv);
     EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, ciphertext,
         &out_len, (const unsigned char *)plaintext, in_len);
     EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, &ciphertext[out_len], &out_len);  

My problem is that these yield wildly different encrypted results.  In fact the java result is 3 or 4 times more bytes.

Comment: @laura OpenSSL discourages use of lower level APIs and expects everyone to use EVP_PKEY... APIs. I am not able to find any equivalent of `EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(ec_key, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE)` in EVP_PKEY API. Are you aware of any API around that ?

Answer (score 2):

Not-Yet-Commons-OpenSSL's ciphers are compatible with "`openssl enc`" command. Your example can be decrypted by this command,

```
  openssl enc -k password -a -d -des -in data.file
```

You can copy the code from the source,

http://cvs.openssl.org/fileview?f=openssl/apps/enc.c&v=1.45.2.5

Answer (score 0):

The [EVP cipher functions](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html) look like the closest parallel.

Comment: I assume from what I have read that the EVP methods are the best way to use OpenSSL.  But what OpenSSL mode/cipher is the not-yet-commons OpenSSL Java object compatible with?  I know that there is overlap between the Java and OpenSSL, but I do not know what methods/modes create compatible encryptions, and I'm pretty new to this area anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL.encrypt() produces base64 output by default. Use OpenSSL.encrypt(alg, pwd, data, false)  to turn that off.